# Первая строка при использовании команды getline записывается в файл пустая

Tags: c++

Что нужно сделать с кодом что бы первая строка бралась `getline` корректно ?

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> // - библиотека работы с потоками ввода и вывода данных в файлах
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    string path = "myFile.txt"; //строка path хранит в себе название файла
    fstream file_read; // присваиваем классу fstream название file_read
    file_read.open(path, fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::trunc);// используя метод open указываем что мы работаем с нашим файлом и на запись и на чтение , trunc удаляет все что в файле было

    int a = 0, j = 0;
    cout << "Введите количество строк , которое будет записано в первый файл: " << endl;
    cin >> a;


    string *massString = new string[a]; /* создаем динамический массив типа string с именем massString */



    if (!file_read.is_open()) // если файл не открылся напишет Error
    {
        cout << "Error" << endl;

    }
    else                            // если файл открылся , то построчно через строку buffer , заносим в первый файл строки , количеством а раз
    {
        string buffer;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Введите текст в первый файл " << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            cin >> buffer;
            file_read << buffer << "\n";
        }

        file_read.close(); // закрываем 
    }

    file_read.open(path, fstream::in | fstream::out);

    if (!file_read.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Error" << endl;

    }
    else                            // если файл открылся , то  выгружаем построчно данные в массив massString
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            getline(file_read, massString[i]);

        }
        file_read.close();
    }

    ofstream file_record("123.txt"); // команда для записи в файл ofstream ( в скобочках путь к файлу)


    if (!file_record.is_open())
    {
        cout << "ERROR" << endl;

    }
    else                                // если файл открылся , то записываем данные из массива massString во второй файл под названием 123.txt
    {
        for (int i = a - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            file_record << massString[i] << "\n";
        }
    }


    delete[] massString;
    file_record.close();
    file_read.close();
}
```

Comment: С вашего кода непонятно, что вы пытаетесь читать_строку или слово? Вы с консоли читаете  слов, записываете в файл, а потом из файла  пытаетесь читать строку. Так эта строка содержит всего одно слово, тут и getline не нужен

Comment: Если использовать просто cin , то  он введенную строку разбивает на строки по пробелам ,  если будет пробел , то из одной строки мы получим две. Я написал getline что бы были строки с возможностью использовать пробел , но первая строка записывается пустая.

Comment: неправильный код вставил , вместо cin >> buffer; нужно вставить getline(file_read, buffer);